# How to reference websites on "\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}" Elsevier Scientific Article template

Tags: bibliographies, elsarticle

[image]

```
@Misc{APAWeb,
  title        = {{Socioeconomic Status}},
  howpublished = {{https://www.apa.org/topics/socioeconomic-status/}},
  note         = {{Accessed: 2019-02-16}},
  url          = {https://www.apa.org/topics/socioeconomic-status/},
  urldate      = {2019-02-16},
}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{elsarticle} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{lineno} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{threeparttable} 
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{mhchem} 

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names} 
\bibliography{XYZ.bib}
```

Comment: Please add a MWE. Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `????` issue arises because the `model1-num-names` bibliography style expects to find a non-empty `year` field in an entry of type `@misc`. The entry at hand contains a field called `urldate`, but none called `year`.

Given that the `model1-num-names` bibliography style does know what to do with a field called `url`, you should probably delete the redundant `howpublished` field. (If you do decide to keep the `howpublished` field, you should encase its contents in a `\url` directive if the contents consist of a URL string.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{XYZ.bib}
@Misc{APAWeb,
  title         = {{Socioeconomic Status}},
  xhowpublished = {\url{https://www.apa.org/topics/socioeconomic-status/}},
  note          = {{Accessed}: 2019-02-16},
  url           = {https://www.apa.org/topics/socioeconomic-status/},
  xurldate      = {2019-02-16},
  year          = 2019,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{elsarticle} 
%% I've commented out all preamble instructions 
%% that are irrelevant to the problem at hand.
%\usepackage{graphicx} 
%\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{lineno} 
%\usepackage{multirow} 
%\usepackage{multicol} 
%\usepackage{threeparttable} 
%\usepackage{lscape} 
%\usepackage{gensymb} 
%\usepackage{textcomp} 
%\usepackage{mhchem} 
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names} % from https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks anywhere in a URL string

\begin{document}
\cite{APaWeb}
\bibliography{XYZ} % don't inlcude the ".bib" extension
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain why you are adding this:

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{XYZ.bib}

?

I have tried adding year, but unfortunately it is not working on my end. :(

Comment: @KaziAurnob - The `filecontents` package lets you create external files -- here, `XYZ.bib` -- on the fly. I used this package in order to provide a standalone compilable solution. In practice, one would never create "real" bib files -- which may contain dozens or even hundreds of bib entries -- in this manner. Instead, one would edit the bib file using an editor program. Please be more specific as to what "it is not working on my end" means. E.g., do you get error and/or warning messages? And, after changing the bib file, did you rerun bibtex for running LaTeX twice more?

Comment: I am working on overleaf, do you think that might be the issue?

Comment: @KaziAurnob - I'm afraid I'm not sure which "issue" you're referring to.

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked.

the "issue" I was referring to was that even after adding the "year" field, the problem sustained. I was working on overleaf.com

when I shifted to miktex, it was solved